# Check function is not working variable meaning unchanged

Tags: jquery

Hello I have a register scrip in jQuery witch only validates a field, everything is working except the last part where I create a variable check and set its meaning to 0. On the checks if everything is okay it will change to 1, if not to 0 and at the end if != to 0 show the next button div. Even if I fill in those fields correctly it doesn't show, and that probably means that the meaning stays unchanged, because if I set a variable meaning to 1 where i was declared  , the button appears. Here is code of my script :

```
<script type="text/javascript">    
        //password validation ==================================
        var check = 0;
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('input[name*="password"]').keyup(validatepass);
        });

        function validatepass(){
                var password = $('input[name="password"]').val();
                var repassword = $('input[name="repassword"]').val();
                var isValid = /^[a-zA-Z0-9]*$/.test(password);
                var length = password.length;

                if (isValid && (length > 4) && (length < 16)){
                    if(password == repassword){
                        $('input[name="password"]').attr('class', 'valid');
                        $('input[name="repassword"]').attr('class', 'valid');
                        check = 1;
                    } else {
                        $('input[name="repassword"]').attr('class', 'invalid');
                        check = 0;
                    }

                    if(password == ""){
                        $('input[name="password"]').attr('class', 'invalid');
                        $('input[name="repassword"]').attr('class', 'invalid');
                        check = 0;
                    } else {
                        $('input[name="password"]').attr('class', 'valid');
                        check = 1;
                    }

                } else {
                    $('input[name="password"]').attr('class', 'invalid');
                    $('input[name="repassword"]').attr('class', 'invalid');
                    check = 0;
                }
        }
        //username validation ========================
         $(function () {

            jQuery('#username').on('input', function () {

                $("#username").removeClass();

                var username = $(this).val();
                var isValid = /^[a-zA-Z0-9]*$/.test(username);
                var length = username.length;
                if (isValid && (length > 4) && (length < 16)){
                    $("#username").addClass("valid");
                    check = 1;
                } else {
                    $("#username").addClass("invalid");
                    check = 0;
                }
            });
        });
        //Email validation-------------------------------
        $(function () {

            jQuery('#email').on('input', function () {

                $("#email").removeClass();

                var username = $(this).val();
                var isValid = /^(([^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/.test(username);
                if (isValid){
                    $("#email").addClass("valid");
                    check = 1;
                } else {
                    $("#email").addClass("invalid");
                    check = 0;
                }
            });
        });
        /// button show if everything is ok 
        $(document).ready(function() {
            if(check != 0){
                $("#loginsubmitbutton2").show();
            }
        });



    </script>
```

Comment: can any1 help with this ?

Comment: Can you provide some HTML to go with this? It's hard to test. Perhaps make a jsfiddle

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/nkq8gc8z/1/ i made this but its not working there for some reason at all cuz on my page the only problem is with the button that should appears everything else is working , the whole jquery code are working as i want to by but my check if every field validate and if they are valid show button are not working

Comment: you forgot to include jQuery, I've done it for you: https://jsfiddle.net/nkq8gc8z/2/

Comment: yes but as u can see the button are not showing even when they are valid the last fuction

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to rework some of your code, have a look at the whole fiddle here:

> https://jsfiddle.net/nkq8gc8z/4/

The main thing I did:

On every input event, check if the amount of `<input>` fields that exist in your form is the same as the amount of `<input>` fields with the class `valid`. Because if that's the case, all your fields are validated and you can show the button.

This means there is no more need for a `check` variable.

What you mainly did wrong was this code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    if(check != 0){
        $("#loginsubmitbutton2").show();
    }
});
```

It checks if the `check` variable is not 0 **AS SOON AS** the page loads. You set your `check` to 0 at the top of your script, meaning it will **ALWAYS** be 0 when this part of your code runs, so the button is never shown.

Comment: tnx you so much again i am not very good at jquery but thanks for explaining everything wont make this mistake again

Comment: @yahoo5000 No problem, make sure you try to understand where you went wrong, next time you start you'll stand stronger :)

Comment: There is a bug with this code try to play with a password field its the best way to understand and get it try to make everything valid and then just add char to pass or repass no matter witch one