# jQuery + CSS text show not working

Tags: jquery, html, css

I need help with my page I am trying to show a hover text with jQuery but it's not working properly.

This is how my page looks:

[image: webpage]

Everything is about those clan selection because ones I put code you will understand more.

jQuery code :

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('input[name="clan"]').mousemove(function(e) {
    var hovertext = $(this).attr('hovertext');
    $('#hovertext').text(hovertext).show();
    $('#hovertext').css('top', e.clientY-275).css('left', e.clientX-330);
  }).mouseout(function() {
    $('#hovertext').hide();
  });
});
```

HTML markup:

```html
<div id="register2">
  <p><b>Registration Step (2/3)</b></p>
  <b>Choose your clan:</b><br /><br />
  <div id="hovertext"></div>
  <form action="reg3.php" method="post">
    <div class="cc-selector-2">
      <input type="hidden" name="village" value="<?php echo $village; ?>">
      <input id="uchiha" type="radio" name="clan" value="uchiha" hovertext="Uchiha clan"/>
      <label class="drinkcard-cc uchiha" for="uchiha"></label>

      <input id="hyuga" type="radio" name="clan" value="hyuga" hovertext="hyuga clan "/>
      <label class="drinkcard-cc hyuga" for="hyuga"></label>

      <input id="senju" type="radio" name="clan" value="senju" />
      <label class="drinkcard-cc senju" for="senju"></label>

      <input id="uzumaki" type="radio" name="clan" value="uzumaki" />
      <label class="drinkcard-cc uzumaki" for="uzumaki"></label>

      <input id="taijutsu" type="radio" name="clan" value="taijutsu" />
      <label class="drinkcard-cc taijutsu" for="taijutsu"></label>

      <input id="noclan" type="radio" name="clan" value="noclan" />
      <label class="drinkcard-cc noclan" for="noclan"></label><br><br>
    </div>
    <input id="loginsubmitbutton2" type="submit" name="next" value="Next"><br><br>
  </form>
</div>
```

and CSS:

```css
#hovertext {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: white;
  color: rebeccapurple;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  z-index: 99999;
}
.cc-selector-2 input {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 999;
}
.uchiha {
  background-image: url(images/clan/uchiha.jpg);
}
.hyuga {
  background-image: url(images/clan/hyuga.jpg);
}
.senju {
  background-image: url(images/clan/senju.jpg);
}
.uzumaki {
  background-image: url(images/clan/uzumaki.jpg);
}
.taijutsu {
  background-image: url(images/clan/taijutsu.jpg);
}
.noclan {
  background-image: url(images/clan/noclan.jpg);
}
.m1 {
  background-image: url(images/ninjas/m1.jpg);
}
.m2 {
  background-image: url(images/ninjas/m2.jpg);
}
.m3 {
  background-image: url(images/ninjas/m3.jpg);
}
.m4 {
  background-image: url(images/ninjas/m4.jpg);
}
.f1 {
  background-image: url(images/ninjas/f1.jpg);
}
.f2 {
  background-image: url(images/ninjas/f2.jpg);
}
.f3 {
  background-image: url(images/ninjas/f3.jpg);
}
.f4 {
  background-image: url(images/ninjas/f4.jpg);
}
.drinkcard-cc {
  cursor: pointer;
  background-size: contain;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 70px;
  -webkit-transition: all 100ms ease-in;
  -moz-transition: all 100ms ease-in;
  transition: all 100ms ease-in;
  -webkit-filter: brightness(1.8) grayscale(1) opacity(.7);
  -moz-filter: brightness(1.8) grayscale(1) opacity(.7);
  filter: brightness(1.8) grayscale(1) opacity(.7);
}
.drinkcard-cc:hover {
  -webkit-filter: brightness(1.2) grayscale(.5) opacity(.9);
  -moz-filter: brightness(1.2) grayscale(.5) opacity(.9);
  filter: brightness(1.2) grayscale(.5) opacity(.9);
}
.drinkcard-cc2 {
  cursor: pointer;
  background-size: contain;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 105px;
  height: 150px;
  -webkit-transition: all 100ms ease-in;
  -moz-transition: all 100ms ease-in;
  transition: all 100ms ease-in;
  -webkit-filter: brightness(1.8) grayscale(1) opacity(.7);
  -moz-filter: brightness(1.8) grayscale(1) opacity(.7);
  filter: brightness(1.8) grayscale(1) opacity(.7);
}
.drinkcard-cc2:hover {
  -webkit-filter: brightness(1.2) grayscale(.5) opacity(.9);
  -moz-filter: brightness(1.2) grayscale(.5) opacity(.9);
  filter: brightness(1.2) grayscale(.5) opacity(.9);
}
```

So if code is like this everything is works but the thing is that it work only on radio button area and I want that it will work on whole image because they are linked with a CSS but when I tried to use a class like `.drinkcard-cc` or other I got no result in place where should be hover text I got dot

Comment: Can you create a snippet or bin for this?

Comment: you mean something like jsfiddle ?

Comment: exactly.. snippet or bin is better. snippet is the best because it's live in the question.

Comment: @yahoo5000 i made you a fiddle and made it work, check my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `mousemove` event is bound to the `<input>` element, making it only fire when you `mousemove` on the actual radio button. jQuery, in a way, is 'stupid', it does not know it should also fire your function on a `mousemove` on the `<label>`, simply because you havn't told it to so.

Look at the following snippet, I changed your code to fit your needs:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    // Bind the mousemove to the label
    $('label').mousemove(function(e) {
        var myRadio = $("input#" + $(this).attr('for')); // Fetch the radio that belongs to the label

        var hovertext = myRadio.attr('hovertext'); // We now have the hovertext
        $('#hovertext').text(hovertext).show();
        $('#hovertext').css('top', e.clientY).css('left', e.clientX);
    }).mouseout(function() {
        $('#hovertext').hide();
    });

    // And bind the mousemove to the input
    $('input[name="clan"]').mousemove(function(e) {

        var hovertext = $(this).attr('hovertext'); // We now have the hovertext

        $('#hovertext').text(hovertext).show();
        $('#hovertext').css('top', e.clientY).css('left', e.clientX);
    }).mouseout(function() {
        $('#hovertext').hide();
    });

 });
```

**EDIT**

https://jsfiddle.net/ssc1kpmj/1 Here's a fiddle, check it out.
Also updated the js I just wrote, because the e.clientY-275 nad the e.clientX-330 made the `<div>` not visible on the screen.

Comment: tnx for help for a snippet it was looking the same as i want to by now will try on my whole page hope will be same result tnx for help

Comment: and maybe you could help me with my other question that i havent respond yet at all http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37378461/check-function-is-not-working-variable-meaning-unchanged its same jquery

Comment: @yahoo5000 I'll have a look